# Apply parseFloat on ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to print Float value on the input field using ng-model. But it's not displaying. If I use value instead of ng-model then it's getting displayed.

Here's my code:

```
<input id="cost" name="cost" type="number" ng-model="parseFloat(cost_per_month)">
```

If I use value insted of ng-model:

```
<input id="cost" name="cost" type="number" value="cost_per_month">
```

Here's my controller:

```
$scope.selectedcost = parseFloat(orgprojects.cost_per_month);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to necessarily use parseFloat on the controller, you could use the number filter to display the model variable in the required format,

```
<input id="cost" name="cost" type="number" ng-model="cost_per_month | number:2">
```

Comment: Removed parseFloat from controller and changed the code as mentioned; but I'm not able to see the value.

Comment: Changing the type to text instead of number works. <input id="cost" name="cost" type="text" ng-model="cost_per_month">

Comment: Yes it should be always a string, mark if the answer helped

Comment: But I want to have input type as number.